# best method to model a roofcorner

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode

I'm modeling a roof of a building. And I want to make a corner of the roof. Does anyone get an Idea what the best way is, to make such a corner? I just stacked them in one another and you can see the corner already, but can how I cut it perfectly now. So can anyone tell me what the best method is to model a roof corner or how I cut them the way they fit together. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: "*Does anyone get an Idea what the best way is*" The "best" way is an opinion based question. You could try using *Knife Project* to slice the intersection

Comment: It's not working pretty well. But thank you for the awnser! :)

Comment: Best way is to look at photos of real references and try to replicate as much as possible from them. There is apex which covers the roof in the corners in real life, and corners will have to be cut as well to allow corner to be straight. Cutting can be done with Knife or Knife Project and topology should be fixed after (if any tris / Ngons etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution after some tests. I used the boolean modifier and used the different settings. Like that, I can separate the parts, and can then delete 
them.

The finished model could look like this:

[image]